# On $\det\left[\frac1{i^2-ij+j^2}\right]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}$ and $\det\left[\frac1{i^2-ij+j^2}\right]_{1\le i,j\le (p-1)/2}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, determinants, p-adic-numbers, quadratic-residues

*QUESTION*. Is my following conjecture true? If true, how to prove it?

**Conjecture**. Let $p$ be a prime with $p\equiv5\pmod 6$, and define the matrices $A_p$ and $B_p$ by 
$$A_p:=\left[\frac1{i^2-ij+j^2}\right]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}
\ \ \text{and}\ \ B_p=\left[\frac1{i^2-ij+j^2}\right]_{1\le i,j\le (p-1)/2}.$$
Then $$\left(\frac{\det A_p}p\right)=\left(\frac 2p\right)\ \ \text{and}\ \ \text{ord}_p(\det B_p)=\frac{p+1}6,$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}p)$ is the Legendre symbol and $\text{ord}_p(x)$ is the $p$-adic order (or valuation) of $x$.

I formulated the conjecture in 2013 and checked it via Mathematica. It appeared in Remark 1.3 of my recent paper [Finite Fields Appl. 56(2019), 285-307].

I think some of you might be able to prove the conjecture. Your comments are welcome!

Comment: How can $\dfrac{p+1}{6}$ be an order modulo $p$? Or do you mean the $p$-valuation of a rational number and the whole matrices are over $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}/p$ ?

Comment: As $p\equiv2\pmod3$, both $\det A_p$ and $\det B_p$ are $p$-adic integers. As usual, $\text{ord}_p(x)$ is the largest $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\equiv 0\pmod {p^n}$.

Comment: Ah, so you do mean the $p$-valuation. I am used to calling it $v_p\left(x\right)$, while $\operatorname{ord}_p\left(x\right)$ stands for the order of an invertible element $x$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.